# Como detectar los números intermedios?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo lo siguiente:

```
var c = "Hola";
var s = c.split('');

for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){

/* s.map(function(x){

return x.toUpperCase();

}); Como realizar este código cada un numero ? */

}
```

Me refiero a como puedo hacer mayúsculas CADA letra del array, pero no todas, sino que en el índice 0, luego en el 2, luego en el 4, luego en el 6, Osea saltandose un índice(se salta el índice 1, el 3, el 5 , etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá la solución mas simple sea esta:

```js
var c = "hola como estas";
var s = c.split('');

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2)
    s[i] = s[i].toUpperCase();

alert(s.join(""));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Arie

Answer (score 2):

Aqui un a version a lo ES6(para variar). Basada en la respuesta de [Bitito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/85740/38468)

```js
var f = false; 
var resultado = ("hola como estas").split('').map(x=> (f = !f) ? x.toUpperCase() : x ).join("");
alert(resultado);
```

Comment: que hace ( f= !f )

Comment: Niega su propio valor y lo asigna a el mismo. Si el valor de `f` es `false`, entoces `!f` retornaria `true` y viceversa.

Comment: y eso con el fin de qué?

Comment: sería como saltarse una letra? ya que es true, false, true ,false ?

Comment: es lo mismo que hacer `var resultado = ("hola como estas").split('').map((x,i)=> !(i%2)? x.toUpperCase() : x ).join("");`

Comment: Buena @ArieCwHat. No sabia que `map` proveia el indice.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, dale una miradita al [operador ternario](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx) de javascript.

Comment: Pero es que f nunca seria igual que !f

Comment: Lee esta documentacion para que tengas una idea sobre el subtitulo Negacion http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_3/operadores.html

Comment: sise lo que es, por eso digo que la negacion de f nunca será igual a su original osea, true es distinto de false y con el operador ternario siempre retornaria la 'x' sin mayuculas, entonces como funciona

Comment: Siempre se niega a si mismo. Por cada iteracion `f` cambia de valor asi: false, true, false, true, false, true... Por lo que el terminario ejecuta el bloque de codigo en base al valor retornado por la expression.

Comment: Entiendo lo que hace, pero el ternario, no evalua una expresion y no una asignación? no deberia evaluar f == !f o algo así ? estoy algo confuso

Comment: Digamos que estas asignando el valor a `f` y después lo estas retornado para que el ternario evalue la expression

Answer (score 0):

Si usas `for` no tenes por qué usar `.map` para este caso.

Siguiendo tu código, podrías hacer algo así con una *flag*:

```
var c = "Hola";
var s = c.split('');
var flag = false;

s.map(function(x){
  flag = !flag;

  if (flag) {
    alert (x.toUpperCase()); 
  }

});
```

Si queres empezar a partir del index 1 simplemente inicias la flag en *true*.

Comment: pero necesito toda la cadena